# Why output of "echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" is empty?

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop

```
inxi -Sx
System:    Host: zika.gattaca.net Kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: GNOME 40.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri)
```

Why do the following commands show nothing?
I do not know if are relevant but they are not defined in the environment.

```
printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"

echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP

wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

https://itsfoss.com/find-desktop-environment/

Comment: Because you aren't running the code underneath a Desktop Environment (GUI)

Comment: can you please detail a bit what you meant, thank you so much.

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/detect-the-desktop-environment-in-linux-command-line/

Comment: The `XDG_` environment variables are set up by the desktop manager (if it conforms to the Common Desktop Environment specification).You're connected to a terminal session (or a serial terminal) without a GUI, without a managed display, without a desktop manager. I infer, from the CDE that setting the `XDG_` variables outside a graphics system is a No-No, a Violation of the Rules.